# Fetch Flask Json data with React (error: 'data' is not defined)

Tags: javascript

I have a simple Flask backend and I'm trying to fetch json data from it in a simple React frontend. However when I run the React code I get an error: `src/App.js Line 8:57: 'data' is not defined no-undef`. From the examples I've seen it seems `data` should be accessible. I'm not trying to do anything complicated with states or effects, I'd like as a first step to be able to simply fetch the Flask json data and print it out in the frontend.

My Flask backend is `hello.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask("__name__")

@app.route('/hello/')
def hello():
    return {'1': 'hello'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

React files. App.js:

```
import React from 'react';

let url = 'http://localhost:8000/hello

function App() {
    fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(console.log(data))

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root))
```

Comment: i'm not a react expert but i did not see where data is defined. So shouldn't there be a variable called data somewhere?

Comment: @Kevin, from the examples I've seen it seems `data` is returned by fetch. They don't define `data` anywhere either as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment you are missing to define the data variable. It's like in the `then` Block where you access the `res`. So maybe it works if you write something like:

```js
function App() {
    fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
```